# How to change orientation of table using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table

I have small `EmployeeCheck` table in SQL server as below:

[image]

I want to select data from this table as below:

[image]

I can do it using cursor and then update query. However, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: How did you create the original table?  The logic between what you have and what you want is . . . unusual.  Why don't you have rows for IT/Sedan for EmpId 100?

Comment: Please don't post images as sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this will get you what you want, but it's a strange requirement.

```
(SELECT DISTINCT EmpId, DeptCheck WHERE DeptCheck IS NOT NULL) D
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT EmpId, VehicleCheck WHERE VehicleCheck IS NOT NULL) V
ON D.EmpID = V.EmpID
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT EmpId, LocationCheck WHERE LocationCheck IS NOT NULL) L
ON L.EmpID = D.EmpID
```